# simple way to identify the user is having the account in Gmail?

Tags: php

Do any one say which is the simple way to identify the user is having the account in Gmail ?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean. What user, in which context?

Comment: The user who logged in to my application

Answer (score 3):

Do a DNS query on the domain portion of the email address and check the MX records to see if they are the ones for Gmail.  This should cover both normal Gmail addresses, as well as domains using Gmail.

Comment: The user might have a Gmail account but be using a different address.

Comment: Well, I don't think assuming that the OP wants to test an email address associated with the account is a stretch.  If not, I change my answer to 'pecl install telepathy'.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot automatically determine whether an arbitrary user has a Gmail account.

Instead, you can ask the user:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="HasGmail" />
<label for="HasGmail">Do you have a Gmail account?</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you ask the user to sign in with their email address and see for yourself if it's a gmail account?

Answer (score 0):

Use the built-in PHP function [stripos](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php) which will return `False` if the email address string does not contain "gmail" (all gmail email accounts, which do not use mail forwarding, contain the "gmail" string).

```
if (stripos($user_email_address, "gmail"))
{
    echo "We have a gmail user!";
}
```